# MVC3/4 Partial View force lazy loaded relations to load

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, lazy-loading, partial-views

I created a Partial View which shows the Asset name, the Waterbody name and the County name. The partial view is based on the Asset model. If I'm in **Assets/Detail** the Detail view (which is working with the Asset model) loads the partial like this:
`@Html.Partial("Summary", Model)`

all is well, all three fields load.

If I am in **AccessInspections/Edit** which works with the AccessInspection model the partial is loaded like this:
`@Html.Partial("Summary", Model.Asset)`

However, the AccessInspection.Asset.Waterbody.Name and AccessInspection.Asset.County.Name do not load. (I do get the Asset.Name value.)

The models are related like this:

Asset
.AssetType (Single)
.LandLocation (Single)
..Waterbody (Single)
...ID
...Name
..County
...ID
...County
.AccessInspections (Collection)

I'm guessing this has to do with Lazy Loading. How can I force the related data to come through?

Answer (score 0):

After sorting out the some things, here's what I had to do.
In Assets I could use Summary (moved back into the Views\Assets folder) as is, passing in the model like so:
`@Html.Partial("Summary", Model)`

In Views\AccessInspections I had to call the @Html.Action for the partial, but the controller had to specify return PartialView(asset) to correctly parse it as a partial. I can call it like this:
`@Html.Action("Summary", "Assets", new { id = Model.Asset.Id })`

The controller code looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Summary(int id = 0)
{  
    Asset asset = db.Assets.Find(id);  
    if (asset == null)  
    {  
        return HttpNotFound();  
    }  
    return PartialView(asset);  
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why it wasn't loading in the first place, but you could also try using `.Include()` to eager load those relationships.